# Cefsharp dialog appears offscreen

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm loading a webpage in cefsharp from my website which just holds fb like plugin in iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Like our Facebook page</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmypage%2F&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId=realappid" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It loads the page fine, but when I click Like button, it shows Facebook login dialog offscreen and I can't bring it to front even I click it from taskbar.

[image]

[image]
In form

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser socialBrowser;

//LOAD FB LIKE PAGE

socialBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://mywebsite.com/fb.html")
{
    RequestHandler = new BrowserRequestHandler()
};
```

Can fb iframe itself is a problem?
This is the BrowserRequestHandler class which is attached to the browser instance.

```
class BrowserRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{

    bool OnBeforePluginLoad(IWebBrowser browser, string url, string policyUrl, WebPluginInfo info)
    {
        return false;
    }


    bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
    {
    }

    void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
    {
    }

    IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        return null;
    }

    bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
    {
    }

    bool OnProtocolExecution(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string url)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
    {
    }

    void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, ref string newUrl)
    {
    }

    bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool OnSelectClientCertificate(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, X509Certificate2Collection certificates, ISelectClientCertificateCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, ref string newUrl)
    {

    }

    bool IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        string url = chromiumWebBrowser.Address;
        if (url.Contains("#download-this-video-mp3"))
        {
            frmMainNew.DownloadVideoFromPage.StartDowbload(url, "mp3");
            return true;
        }
        else if (url.Contains("#download-this-video-mp4"))
        {
            frmMainNew.DownloadVideoFromPage.StartDowbload(url, "mp4");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool IRequestHandler.OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool IRequestHandler.OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void IRequestHandler.OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
    {

    }

    bool IRequestHandler.OnSelectClientCertificate(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, X509Certificate2Collection certificates, ISelectClientCertificateCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void IRequestHandler.OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
    {

    }

    bool IRequestHandler.OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }


    void IRequestHandler.OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }

    public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage)
    {
        callback.Continue(true);
        return true;
    }

    public IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Are you using `WPF` or `WinForms`? It's not really clear from your screenshot what the problem is. More detail is required.

Comment: Latest version - WinForms

Comment: Exact version please

Comment: CEF 75.1.14+gc81164e+chromium-75.0.3770.100
Chromium 75.0.3770.100

Comment: That's the CEF version.  The latest CefSharp version is 75.1.143. The screenshot you've provided doesn't clearly show what's going on for me anyway. You can test with the CEF Sample application,  details here https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: You are right,  I do have 75.1.143 version of the cefsharp and the problem is I can't see FB login screen other than that is visible in mouse-hover preview from the taskbar. If I click its preview, it does not come on screen as what normal windows do.

Comment: Moreover, If I right-click on the preview->maximize, it appears normally in the full-screen window.

Comment: Due to the nature of the software, I can't share its video here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by ILifeSpanHandler

```
public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
{
      ChromiumWebBrowser wb = new ChromiumWebBrowser(targetUrl);
      wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(windowInfo.Width, windowInfo.Height);
      wb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(windowInfo.X, windowInfo.Y);

      newBrowser = wb;

      return false;
}
```

Comment: I will still wait for someone to answer if it can be fixed without using ILifeSpanHandler.